# Is Update Interval Accurate for Location Updates?

Tags: android, location

I am currently trying to work with Google Play Location Updates for an Android project.

I have set the updateInterval for LocationRequests at 5000 (5 seconds) and fastestInvertval also at 5000:

```
mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
```

I am now thinking of getting rid of old code that dealt with time-stamps and calculating speed through getting the difference between the two times. I've been hesitant to do so because I though that maybe the updateInterval for the LocationRequests would be inaccurate, and would have large margins of error.

My question is:

**Is LocationRequests' Update Interval accurate so that I could remove safeguards such as the time stamps? If so, what is the approximate margin of error?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The updateInterval is the fastest it will return a new value.  It could be close.  It could take twice that.  It could take 100 times that.  It could take 8 hours, if someone went inside.  Also very few GPS chips are going to give a new result more than once every 30 seconds, at least as of the last time I checked.  In short, use timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

The location updates may be faster than this rate if another app is receiving updates at a faster rate, or slower than this rate, or there may be no updates at all (if the device has no connectivity, for example)([source](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html#location-request)).

It all depends on the level of accuracy that you need, some samples might come several seconds late. You would have to see if for your application this is acceptable or not. You can always retrieve the timestamp of your location sample from the [location.getTime()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getTime()) method if you need to check.